# What is the best non intrusive way to support audit events logging with Istio and Kubernetes

Tags: security, istio, audit

What is the best non intrusive way to support logging audit events with Istio and Kubernetes.

The preferred solution better be at the mesh level without changing the application code.

There is a need to have special formatting and to comply with the Cloud Auditing Data Federation [CADF](https://www.dmtf.org/standards/cadf) format using Istio mesh for security audit of events.

Comment: I'm not sure I undserstand correctly, but the simplest kind of Istio logging is Envoy’s access logging. You can choose between JSON and text by setting accessLogEncoding, more about it [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/).

Comment: This is not configurable and is not really supporting the 7w's of CADF format  @jt97